# How to run a code once a week, every sunday for exaple, im using Rails 4.2.5 and ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i need to show a random item from an array that changes once a week.
I'm getting the random item like this.

```
<% @item.sample(1).each do |item| %>
```

It works just fine but it makes the change everytime the page is reloaded.

What do i need to do for the code to run once a week?

Comment: Cron helps with running code according to a schedule, but you'll probably also want to save your new selection whenever that happens... i.e. in a database, in a YAML file, etc.

Comment: @eeeeeean found a site point article about! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want cronjobs. A ruby library doing this that you can incorporate into your Rails project would be https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: I check it out, but I don't quite get how to do what I want. should I use it, put the code on the schedule file and just the output on the web view ?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite got it at first but a few Google searches did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroku, you can use the Heroku Scheduler https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

It can save you some glue code and just write your logic.